# generate PDF calling information from database in javaFX

Tags: java, database, javafx, latex, pdf-generation

Good day to all. I am currently building a program that covers the review of product warranty applications. I'm doing it in javaFX using Netbeans. The program has the following scenes:

1. a screen where the information of each guarantee request is entered. all the information is stored in a table in a database. The interaction between the program and the database is done, in effect, through JDBC.
2. a screen where you can see a table that shows all the requests that have been saved. if a row is selected, a button that carries the third scene all the data of the request that was selected is enabled.
3. a screen where all the data of the tests that are made to the selected guarantee application are entered. The results are also stored in another table in the database.

After the application is evaluated, a warranty review report must be generated. Currently this format is generated in pdf from excel. What I want to do is that from the data results of the tests stored in the database I can dynamically generate the pdf formats from the program in javaFX. Is there a plugin to write these documents automatically? I'm good at writing texts in LaTEX, so if there is a way to generate the latex format from the program and call the necessary information from the database, it would be perfect. Thanks in advance for the help. Any indication or idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have two core requirements:

1. Fetch data from the database suitable for reporting
2. Generate the report(s) in PDF from JavaFX but can fall back to LaTEX

What you really need seems like a PDF library for Java.  I can suggest [iText](https://itextpdf.com/) and [Docmosis](https://www.docmosis.com/) as good options (please note I work for Docmosis) - both are commercial for commercial products so you would have to buy.

Assuming you are using one of these libraries, the process for each report is:

1. execute the query to fetch the appropriate data for the report
2. manipulate the data if required to make the reporting stage simple
3. generate the report

Using iText you would write the query, the manipulation code and then the code to layout the report including the data.
Using Docmosis you would write the query, possibly some manipulation code (Docmosis can also work directly with your ResultSet) and the code to execute the report.  The layout is designed in the template (Word or Libre Office Writer).

When you mention writing "these documents automatically" I assume you mean creating the PDF file format, which iText and Docmosis can do.  If you mean creating the report layout itself, then you always need to design/write something to make the report do what you require.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Tank you so much for your response,  please read my answer below and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your response Paul! I had found something related to the libraries you mentioned, and indeed something like what I'm looking for. I notice that you are more in the subject. then, you do not know bookstore, preferably free, that gives me the possibility of doing the following (pseudo code):

1. take the row from the database
2. Save the information of that row in the attributes of a created class.
3. create text1: "the guarantee with reference" + object.attribute1 + "was not approved in view of the physical revision test indicated that" + object.attribute2 + "
4. create text2: "..."
5. ...
6. create the text n: "..."
7. take text 1 and place it in the header of the pdf document
8. Take text 2, put it in bold and place it in the subtitle
9. Generate a table and fill it with the content of text 3, 4 ...
10. compile all information as a pdf, (word file, xls or others if possible)

I am clear that with the libraries that you recommend you can easily make items from
1 to 8, but I do not know if it is possible to enter the texts within a template created, so that the library accommodates all the texts in the respective zones of the template file. I imagine that this can easily be done with Latex, since everything is written in plain text.

I found a library called Java LaTeX Report ([JLR](http://www.nixo-soft.de/tutorials/jlr/JLRTutorial.html)) that allows me to do what I want. This information may be useful to someone. Thank you again for your answer Paul, if you consider the libraries that you mention do the job  more easily than JLR please let me know!

Comment: Hello Nelson.  It is often best to stick with what you know / are comfortable with.  Since JRL fits in this way for you definitely try it out.  I suggest firstly creating *simple* example that tests the full flow from one end to the other - from inputs to create the document.  Then you'll be able to run more complex tests.  This approach should help to discover quickly where the challenges are.